# Autolayout alignment to a common object: result not as expected

Tags: ios, autolayout

Here is my custom prototype cell layout in storyboard:

[image]

I have defined two texts (a smaller UITextField on top and a bigger UITextView at the button) and have made both of them to have a 14 points horizontal spacing from the UIImageView on the left hand side.

However when I run the code, I get this:

[image]

Apparently the bigger UITextView has shifted slightly to the right hand side.

Attached are the constraint definitions:

[image]

and
[image]

Why it is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the widgets are aligned properly by autolayout. The problem lies with the UITextView. It displays the text with some leading space. As a result the texts of both widget appear not to align to each other.